# Add more object(stdClass) with the same name with php

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I created with php a new object with new stdClass.

```
$response->node1->node2->summary = new stdClass();
$response->node1->node2->summary->text = "lorem ipsum";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $response );
echo "</pre>"
```

This is the result:

```
object(stdClass)#17 (1) {
  ["node1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
    ["node2"]=>
    object(stdClass)#12 (1) {
      ["summary"]=>
      object(stdClass)#16 (1) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(11) "lorem ipsum"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How is it possible to create more objects in a loop with the name "summary"?
The result should look like this:

```
object(stdClass)#17 (1) {
  ["node1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
    ["node2"]=>
    object(stdClass)#12 (1) {
      ["summary"]=>
      object(stdClass)#16 (1) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(11) "lorem ipsum"
      }
      ["summary"]=>
      object(stdClass)#17 (1) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(11) "different content"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in a for-loop, I always get the content which is the final one in the for loop.

thx 4 helping me.

Comment: Sounds like you keep rewriting over the same `summary` object as it shouldn't have multiple `objects` with the same `key`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? How would you distinguish these different elements with the same key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two properties with the same name; `$foo->summary` has to refer to a single thing.

What you can do is set the value of that property to be an array:

```
$response->node1->node2->summary = [];
```

And then add items to that array:

```
$response->node1->node2->summary[] = $summary;
```

This is just the same as setting a plain variable, and the array can be used in all the same ways.

(All of this would probably be clearer if you used classes for the various nodes, rather than a big nest of `stdClass` objects, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you have a good reason for doing it this way.)